# Did Unturned actually used to be a Roblox game?

Tags: roblox, unturned

I was scrolling through Steam and found the game "Unturned", I thought it was an interesting game and I decided to research it.

After a while, I found out that Unturned used to be a Roblox game but due to some bugs in the system they made it into a Steam game, but I can't still make sure if this is true.

Is this statement true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, Unturned was not originally a ROBLOX game. It was created by a ROBLOX game creator.**

Unturned was not originally a ROBLOX game.

But it *almost* was...

Unturned was created by Nelson Sexton, a user who created extremely popular games on the ROBLOX platform under the username [DeadzoneZackZak](https://roblox.wikia.com/wiki/Community:DeadzoneZackZak). One of Nelson's most popular ROBLOX creations was a game called "[Deadzone](https://roblox.wikia.com/wiki/Community:DeadzoneZackZak/Deadzone)" (which was a very similar to another popular game from that time, [Apocalypse Rising](https://roblox.wikia.com/wiki/Community:Gusmanak/Apocalypse_Rising)).

After the massive success of Deadzone, Nelson announced that he was going to create a sequel to Deadzone titled "Deadzone 2". This is the game that eventually became Unturned, and it is why the concept and mechanics of Unturned are very similar to those of Deadzone. Nelson used his knowledge of Lua scripting and Java programming to build Unturned in Unity instead of the ROBLOX game engine, which all of his previous games had been in.

[When Unturned initially released on Steam, many of DeadzoneZackZak's fans began testing and playing the game](https://blog.roblox.com/2014/07/from-roblox-game-dev-to-steam-sensation/), sharing it with friends, and posting videos of it online. This is what gave Unturned its initial boost in popularity and lead to its early widespread recognition.

So while Unturned *is* a spiritual successor to a ROBLOX game, and it was created by a developer who gained recognition from ROBLOX, and the idea originally was for it to be a ROBLOX game, Unturned never was a ROBLOX game itself.

Comment: _".. used his knowledge of Lua scripting and Java programming to build Unturned in Unity"_ - ?? Unity doesn't use either of those languages..

Comment: That's true. One of the great things about programming is that a lot of the core concepts are the same accross languages, so once you've learned one language, it is much easier to transition those skills over to another coding scenario even if it is in a different language :)

Answer (score -5):

Yes, it was a Roblox game, and I am 100% sure of it. They eventually decided to turn it into a steam game and that's when it become one of the first games to become its own game off of Roblox.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this?